# How to reconstruct ensemble of trees from random forest?

Tags: classification, random-forest

I have a great prediction yet I am unsure how to uncover how the results were generated?

Comment: Can you expand on this question a little?  What else to you know about the "great prediction"?

Comment: If you mean reading the forest by looking at each tree and trying to understand what is going on, don't do it, you'll fail to see anything in such a complex, randomized structure. RF is just a black box method, its models are not intended to describe data (as usual in machine learning).

Answer (score 1):

From the trees attributed to each class's output you can do a tree search on the similarities. You could do it manually, but that would be as tedious as examining the weights on a Neural network. So you want to find the overlaps in the decision tree structures. This can look for various features depending upon the problem.

Eg. you can see if there is statistically more preference for certain nodes to be parents of other nodes giving a hierarchical structure. You just search all nodes and find if there is more than average having certain children. Do a distribution test to show its beyond a random chance to have consistently those children and that reveals structure of the problem you analyzed. 
Best.

Comment: As I understand it is possible to reconstruct the structure but it is impossible to assign class specific lineage of nodes. Here is my problem. I have a binary problem (presence/absence) of variable that can be predictive of one of 4 classes (as single and as joint for example combination of 5 variables). I am getting high prediction relying on top 20 by VIMP out of 1500 variables). I have to extract the specific combinations at least some of them

Comment: Yes, so you just look at the top 20 you rely on, and find the patterns of similarity for the joint. The joint combinations giving you the prediction contain the information of the variable associations.

Comment: Oh yeah and you just do correlation analysis like a